# Cant get connected to wired/wireless network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

i m using ubuntu 12.04 LTS version on my asus laptop(64bit). My problem is that  i cant get connected to network(wifi/wired LAN). System not showing any connections which are available. But i can get internet through a wireless usb modem. What i m missing here????

```
rfkill list all

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
4: phy2: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I tried this- `sudo rfkill unblock all` still no change.
plz replay....thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a driver issue. Please, check your wireless and wired adapter type and see whether you have the correct drivers.

One other solution would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04, which will probably contain newer drivers.

If you insist on 12.04, then try the compat-drivers (http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable).

When I was using 12.04, compat-drivers did it for me. In 13.04, I had no issues with network adapter drivers.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thnx for replaying. I downloaded the compact driver as you said. But i dont know what to do with that file.. m not expert in ubuntu. Can you help me with that??  thnx.

Comment: Wow, finally i got it right. I m now able to connect through wifi.Installed a compact driver successfully. thanku again